# ORA-02289: sequence does not exist, however sequence is aleady exist in database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-mvc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been working on a java spring project, in which I have created a class whose sole purpose is to record the request body for every service have been called in the database.

The table contains a primary key named as transaction_id and other fields which is required to records the request. The model of the tables in Java looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ForntEndLogHistory")
public class FrontEndLog {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="id_generator", sequenceName = "id_seq2", allocationSize=1)
    private Long transactionId;
    private String request;
}
```

In the database, I have created one sequence named as **id_seq2** whereas **id_seq1** already exists:

**Newly created id_seq2:**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "id_seq2"  MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
commit;
```

**Already exists id_seq1 dll:**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "id_seq1"  MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 3467 NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

**case 1:**

whenever I trigger any services from the postman with below sequence generator with sequence name id_seq2 I get the error "sequence does not exist". However, the sequence is already there in DB.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="id_generator", sequenceName = "id_seq2", allocationSize=1)
    private Long transactionId;
```

The project war file is successfully deployed on the server. After that whenever the service is trigger from the postman following error is occurred:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator.generate(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:654)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:646)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:642)
    at com.etisalat.mwallet.data.BaseDAO.save(BaseDAO.java:49)
    at com.etisalat.mwallet.service.impl.LoggerService.logFrontEnd(LoggerService.java:59)
    at com.etisalat.mwallet.service.impl.LoggerService.logFrontEndSuccess(LoggerService.java:29)
    at com.etisalat.mwallet.rest.config.ResponseFilter.doFilter(ResponseFilter.java:180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:774)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4845)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1501)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
```

**case 2:**

Afterward for testing purpose, I have change the sequence name from id_seq2 to id_seq1 and redeployed the code on server and surprisely I am able to trigger the service sucessfully.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="id_generator", sequenceName = "id_seq1", allocationSize=1)
    private Long transactionId;
```

Output:

> {
>
> "responseCode": "0"
>
> }

I have no idea where I made a mistake as in my point of view, there is something which I have missed in sequence generator.

Comment: Is it in the correct schema, does the DB user see the sequence, is it in the proper tablespace... Figure that out first.

Comment: Yes, it belongs to the correct scheme and SEQUENCE_OWNER for both sequence is also the same as "AAK".

Comment: Just a remark: the max value is 10^28 - 1, approx. 2^84 so would not fit in a long (2^63).

Comment: Normally in Oracle you don't give objects forced lowercase names. Perhaps Spring is generating a reference to `id_seq2`, which does not exist because you actually created `"id_seq2"`. (This might not be the issue as it seems to work with `"id_seq1"`, but it's a complication you surely don't need.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *missing* sequence that *exists* may be caused from two reasons:

1) the sequence exists in a different schema that you are connected with

in this case you must reference `schema_owner`.`schema_name`

2) the sequence exists in a different schema *and you have no privileges to access it*

You should first realize in which schema the *existing* sequence is created.

You can verify it with the following query (substitute the sequence name as required)

```
select OWNER, OBJECT_NAME SEQUENCE_NAME
from all_objects where object_type = 'SEQUENCE' 
and lower(object_name) = 'id_seq1';
```

If you see nothing, the sequence either doesn't exists or it exists in a different schema as you are connected with and you have no `SELECT` priviledge on it.

In case you use a sequence from a different schema than your Hibernate connection user (which is rather a usual case), you must use the [`schema`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html#schema()) parameter of the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation and pass the propper schema owner.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the sequence must exist in the same schema as the schema/user you log into. If you login as an other user then you can try this rather rude solution.

```
create public synonym "id_seq2" for "id_seq2";
grant select on "id_seq2" to public;
```

Or try to figure out what privs and synonyms you have om "id_seq1" and apply that to "id_seq2" as well.

Comment: God forbid using double quotes when naming Oracle objects!

Comment: Agree, but it was in the example, and if it is in the create statement, you better continue :)

Comment: Sadly, yes. I should have put that comment under the question (would make more sense).